# How can I mass assign parameters in a polymorphic association with Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have this code in one of my Models

```
class Admin::About < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address1, ..., :assets_attributes 

  has_many :assets, as: :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
```

This in the Polymorphic table

```
class Admin::Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :imageable_id, :imageable_type, :position, :image 

  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

  has_attached_file :image
```

And in the form I added this

```
<%= f.fields_for :admin_assets do |asset_fields| %>
  <%= asset_fields.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit the data with the image I got this error

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: admin_assets
```

I can't find the problem. Perhaps something is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `admin_assets` attribute. I think you mean `assets_attributes`. It's what you have defined here `accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets` and then above in `attr_accessible :address1, ..., :assets_attributes`.

Change your `fields_for` to:

```
<%= f.fields_for :assets_attributes do |asset_fields| %>
```

Comment: Hey, seems that it worked with the protected attribute, but now I have this error, `undefined method '[]' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd4a8cd7a38>`

Comment: did you specify `multipart: true` in your `form_for`?

Comment: Oh, it worked now. I just edited :assets_attributes for :assets and added `@admin_about.assets.build` in **edit** action